Automatically adjust screen resolution when sharing the screen on Zoom / Microsoft Teams
My monitor resolution is 2560p. Sometimes when I share my screen on meetings, participants with smaller monitors are struggling to read the displayed text. As a workaround, I manually lower my resolution to 1080p, and once the meeting is over I revert to the original resolution.
I wonder if it is possible to set Zoom or Microsoft Teams to automatically adjust the screen resolution once I share the screen (and recover the original resolution afterwards). I couldn't find such setting.
Thanks!

I don't think there is an option to automatically alter the screen resolution.
But if you size the application you want to share to a decent size, and you only share the view of that application, it should not zoom in for others.

A small caveat with sharing a window: certain regular UI elements (popups/dialogs, tooltips and even Win32 dropdowns) may be different windows and will not be visible to viewers.
